# Vim press <cr> multiple time

Tags: vim

How do you simplify this

```
inoremap <C-S-Tab> <cr><cr><cr><cr>
```

to this?

```
inoremap <C-S-Tab> <cr>*4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being an insert mode mapping,

```
inoremap <C-S-Tab> <cr><cr><cr><cr>
```

can't be "simplified" with a count because numbers are printable characters too. You want four `<CR>`s, your mapping has four `<CR>`s: it's perfectly fine as-is.

There are a few ways to "complexify" it, though…

```
inoremap <expr> <C-S-Tab> repeat('<CR>', 4)
```

uses an "expression mapping" which computes the expression at runtime, see `:help <expr>`, `:help repeat()`.

```
inoremap <C-S-Tab> <C-o>4a<CR><Esc>i
```

leaves insert mode for one normal mode command and then does `a<CR>` four times before coming back to insert mode.

---

Note that `<C-S-Tab>` is not a portable combo as it is indistinguishable from `<S-Tab>` in most environments.

Answer (score 0):

how about use record function like using 'r' to record return press then use 4@r to execute 4 times?